# save and reload text of Textbox

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am programming for Windows Phone 8.1.
I have lots of **(100)** Textbox. **They have 3-4 lines**. What is the best way to save text of them and reload text again?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the `Settings` option from the `Isolated Storage` to store the values?

[Here's](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-ReadSave-bb2ae9ca) a good sample you could follow.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. But this is good for values not Textbox with 2-3 line. When I want to save Textbox with 2-3 line. Visual studio instead break line, replace space!